# Bug when scrolling through the similar questions list

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, similar-questions

Write the title of your question, wait for "similar questions" to load, scroll it, complete your title, wait for the "similar questions" list to update, scroll again... (on FireFox windows)

[image: double image]

Comment: Not reproduced on Firefox Android 75.0.0-beta.6 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgmEH.jpg --- Also I have no "wait" time, it's instant, and the "answer(s)" background isn't double-struck.

Comment: Similarly not reproducible on Chrome 81.0.444.122 with Windows 10.

Comment: The double text from screenshot also consistently happens to me, Firefox 76.0.1 on Arch Linux.